# Merge [class-attribute] and [class-attributes] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [class-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-attribute) and [class-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-attributes) tags appear to be interchangeable; there doesn't seem to be any difference between the two.  I propose that they be merged.

In particular, I propose that [class-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-attribute) should be a synonym of [class-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-attributes).  (I don't have enough reputation to suggest the synonym, myself.)